# Set Filetype Content disposition in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

I have a kml file that I have set the mime type for using

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml" />
```

However if you click the link to a kml file in Chrome it will download automatically but redirect to a 404 page. Is there anyway to set a specific file extension's Content Disposition using web.config?